# OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException on Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, selenium

```
namespace FindElementCommands2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form/");


            Thread.Sleep(5000);


            bool a = driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Partial")).Enabled;
            Console.WriteLine(a);

            driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Partial Link Test")).Click();




        }
    }
}
```

Hi there,

I'm a beginner to Selenium with C#.  I'm trying to click on the link Partial Link Test using PartialLinkText locator, but it keeps on complaining that element is not interactable in Application Output in Mac.  Please give some idea on what is wrong.  When I try if the element is disabled or enabled, it returns True which means it is enabled.  It returns True in the console.

Comment: <strong>Partial Link Test</strong>
<a title="Automation Practice Form" href="http://toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/"><strong>Partial Link Test</strong></a>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace StackOverFlow.Answer.Selenium.PartialLinkText
{
   class Class1
   {
       public static IWebDriver driver;
       public static WebDriverWait wait;
       public static int timeOut = 30;

       [Test]
       [Category("ClickPartilLink")]
       public void LoginFail()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Get instance Chrome Browser");
           driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), OptionsChrome());

           Console.WriteLine("Acess demo site");
           driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");

           Console.WriteLine("Waiting Element to click");
           WaiElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'Best Sellers')]"));

           Console.WriteLine("Total Link 'Best Sellers'");
           driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Best")).Click();

           Console.WriteLine("Close Chrome Browser");
           driver.Close();

           Console.WriteLine("Kill instance Driver.");
           driver.Quit();
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Wait elements
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="locator"></param>
       private void WaiElement(By locator)
       {
           wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut));
           wait.Until(condition: ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator));
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// fill 
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="locator"></param>
       /// <param name="text"></param>
       private void Fill(By locator, string text)
       {
           WaiElement(locator);
           driver.FindElement(locator).SendKeys(text);
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// click on elements 
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="locator"></param>
       private void Click(By locator)
       {
           WaiElement(locator);
           driver.FindElement(locator).Click();
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// return text from element
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="locator"></param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       private string GetText(By locator)
       {
           WaiElement(locator);
           return driver.FindElement(locator).Text;
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// set up what capabilites chrome will take
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns></returns>
       private ChromeOptions OptionsChrome()
       {
           ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
           chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
           chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
           chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
           return chromeOptions;
       }
   }
}
```